# Is there a way to access outer class in the nested class in python?

Tags: python, nested-class

just a very simple thing, is there a way to access outer class from the inner class definition,  like this:

```
class Model:
  class Options:
    model = Model   <-- error!
```

I nest Options inside Model because semantically these Options exist only in the scope of model, so it seems appropriate.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Why would you want to store the (outer) *class* in a (inner) *class variable*?

Comment: I think this is more of a design implementation flaw than a language problem.

Comment: I don't have to store it in a variable, but I'd like to use the outer class in the inner class, since they are semantically related.  Variable is just an example...

Comment: You can, but not at class level (as that's evaluate at class definition time, while methods usually don't get called before the class definitions finish running).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is exactly what you wanted but try:

```
class Model:
    class Option:
        @property
        def model(self): return Model
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can at least instantiate the outer class in a method of the inner class:

```
class Model:
    class Options:
        def __init__(self):
            model = Model()
```

Comment: but then if you instantiate `Options` in `Model.__init__` you'll recurse.

Comment: just do `model = Model` instead of `model = Model()`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class Model:
    pass

class Options:
    model = Model
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to do the assignment after the class definition.

```
class Model:
  class Options:
    pass

Model.Options.model = Model
```